# Google form embedded code not working after click Clear Form

Tags: iframe, google-forms, content-security-policy

When I use Google form embedded code then it's working fine. But when i click on Clear Form button then it has redirected to the original google form URL without "?embedded=true" parameter.

So, we will get this error
[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://docs.google.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

Let me know How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your page is being framed by docs.google.com. If you want to allow that you will need to set the following directive instead: "frame-ancestors docs.google.com;"

Comment: Thank for the reply, How can I set "frame-ancestors" in an iframe?

Comment: If it is your iframe, you should find out where Content-Security-Policy is being set. It should be set in a response header. It could be that the default setting for frame-src is 'none',.